# Binding a tree view structure using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, treeview, structure, using

I am binding a tree view structure using a loop. Is there any way to bind this using knockout where I dont have to use loops?

Below is the loop I am using to generate tree view:

```
var items = viewModel.TreeView();
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    if (items[i].ParentMenuID == 0) {
        var html = '<li menuId="' + items[i].MenuID + '"><span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>';
        html += '<span><a href="#" name="basenode" href="javascript:void(0);">' + items[i].MenuName + '</a></span></li>';
        $("#ulTree").append(html);
    }
    else {
        var html = '<ul><li menuId="' + items[i].MenuID + '"><span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>';
        html += '<span><a href="#" name="endnode" href="javascript:void(0);">' + items[i].MenuName + '</a></span></li></ul>';
        $("#ulTree li[menuId='" + items[i].ParentMenuID + "']").append(html);
        $($("#ulTree li[menuId='" + items[i].ParentMenuID + "']").find(".arrow")[0]).addClass("collapse collapsible");
    }
}
```

Output of the above code is below:

```html
<li menuid=1>
<span class="arrow collapse collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
<span><a href="#" name="basenode">PARENT</a></span>
<ul style="display: none;">
<li menuid="222">
<span class="arrow collapse collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
<span><a href="#" name="endnode">NODE</a></span>
<ul style="display: none;">
<li menuid="223">
<span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>
<span><a href="#" name="endnode">1121</a></span>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Where's the Knockout code? What have you tried? Debugged? Did you read KO documentation and/or do the tutorials?

Answer (score 4):

You can recursively bind a tree-like structure using [named templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) in Knockout. E.g.:

```js
var viewModel = {
  TreeView: ko.observable({
    childNodes: [
      {
        id: 1,
        childNodes: [ {id: 2, childNodes: [{id: 3, childNodes: [] }] } ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        childNodes: [ {id: 5, childNodes: [] } ]
      }
    ]
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel.TreeView());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="node">
<li menuid="data bind with attr binding">
<span class="arrow collapse collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
<span><a href="#" name="endnode">NODE</a></span>
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'node', foreach: childNodes }">
</ul>
</li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'node', foreach: childNodes }"></ul>
```